# Transact SQL Subquery calling a function incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

I get an incorrect syntax near '.' and can't seem to identify why in the following code:

```
select 
o.object_id,
(select top 1 Zone from dbo.getzone(o.object_id)) as Zone from object as o
```

getzone is a table-valued Function that works perfectly when I reference it directly, or if I put a specific object_id in, but everytime I try to make it dynamic, I get the syntax error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your alias is wrong. The final part of the statement should say 'from object o'

Comment: You are correct, the aliasing for object was incorrect.

However, changing that doesn't help the actual syntax error that was firing on this part of the code: dbo.getzone(o.object_id)

Comment: I would try what @Necreax said, but you might also try putting brackets around your object table and object_id column. Both are reserved words, which it may not like. Example [object] instead of just object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You need to have a scalar version that returns only one result. It can be just a wrapper script if you want. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getSingleZone](@object_id varchar(20))
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Zone varchar(20)
select @Zone = max(Zone) from dbo.getzone(@object_id)
return @Zone 
END

select 
o.object_id,
dbo.getSingleZone(o.object_id) as Zone from object o
```

I don't know your data types, so I guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your alias

```
select  o.object_id, 
        (select top 1 Zone from dbo.getzone(o.object_id)) as Zone 
from object AS o
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The alias doesn't seem to be the issue though, as I still get a syntax error call on the Function call.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing the problem, but this seems to work. Using the name of a built-in function (`OBJECT_ID`) as a column name might not be helping.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa2388/1) example or code below.

```
-- TVF without parameter.
create function dbo.GetZone()
  returns table as
  return
    select Id, Letter
      from
      ( values ( 1, 'Aleph' ), ( 2, 'Beth' ), ( 3, 'Gimmel' ) ) as Letters( Id, Letter );
go

-- TVF with parameter;
create function dbo.GetZone2( @Id as Int )
  returns table as
  return
    select Id, Letter
      from dbo.GetZone() where Id = @Id;
go

select * from dbo.GetZone();
select * from dbo.GetZone2( 2 );

-- Sample table and data.
declare @Objects as table ( Id Int Identity, Letter VarChar(16) );
insert into @Objects values ( 'Alpha' ), ( 'Beta' ), ( 'Gamma' );
select * from @Objects;

-- Correlated subquery.
select O.Id, O.Letter as [Greek],
  ( select top 1 Letter from dbo.GetZone( ) where Id = O.Id ) as [Hebrew]
  from @Objects as O;
select O.Id, O.Letter as [Greek],
  ( select top 1 Letter from dbo.GetZone2( O.Id ) ) as [Hebrew]
  from @Objects as O;

-- Houseclean.
drop function dbo.GetZone;
drop function dbo.GetZone2;
```